# XPath 2.0:reference earlier context in another part of the XPath expression

Tags: xpath, count, distinct-values

in an XPath I would like to focus on certain elements and analyse them:

```
...
<field>aaa</field>
...
<field>bbb</field>
...
<field>aaa (1)</field>
...
<field>aaa (2)</field>
...
<field>ccc</field>
...
<field>ddd (7)</field>
```

I want to find the elements who's text content (apart from a possible enumeration, are unique. In the aboce example that would be bbb, ccc and ddd.

The following XPath gives me the unique values:

```
distinct-values(//field[matches(normalize-space(.), ' \([0-9]\)$')]/substring-before(., '(')))
```

Now I would like to extent that and perform another XPath on all the distinct values, that would be to count how many field start with either of them and retreive the ones who's count is bigger than 1.

These could be a field content that is equal to that particular value, or it starts witrh that value and is followed by " (". The problem is that in the second part of that XPath I would have refer to the context of that part itself and to the former context at the same time.

In the following XPath I will - instead of using "." as the context- use c_outer and c_inner:

```
distinct-values(//field[matches(normalize-space(.), ' \([0-9]\)$')]/substring-before(., '(')))[count(//field[(c_inner = c_outer) or starts-with(c_inner, concat(c_outer, ' ('))]) > 1]
```

I can't use "." for both for obvious reasons. But how could I reference a particular, or the current distinct value from the outer expression within the inner expression?

Would that even be possible?

Answer (score 0):

XQuery can do it e.g.

```
  for $s 
  in distinct-values(
    //field[matches(normalize-space(.), ' \([0-9]\)$')]/substring-before(., '(')))
  where count(//field[(. = $s) or starts-with(., concat($s, ' ('))]) > 1
  return $s
```

Comment: I didn't watch try it carrefully, but I believe you can do it with XPath 2.0 with two succesive for loop, like that : for $s 
in distinct-values(
//field[matches(normalize-space(.), ' \([0-9]\)$')]/substring-before(., '(')), $y in //field[(. = $s) or starts-with(., concat($s, ' ('))] return $s[count($y) > 1]